# GPRS Connection on a Windows 8 Tablet Using C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, gprs

I am developing an app for a Windows 8 tablet using C# and I need to write a module that creates a GPRS connection using a SIM card.

I have tried searching for this but most results I find talk about a GPRS connection either for Windows CE or Windows Mobile and I presume the code for Windows 8 would be different.

If anyone can give me some advice on how I can create this module or link me to some websites that may explain how I can achieve this I would be great full.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're programming an app in the environment formerly known as Metro, you need [these WinRT APIs.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn391779.aspx)
There are C# code examples provided.

This is not to be confused with the Windows 8 desktop, which has its own separate set of APIs [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323269%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

These APIs are valid for LTE, UMTS/HSPA etc as well as GPRS.

Comment: I am actually writing the app for Windows 8 desktop; I can't really remember now but there is a reason why my app wouldn't really work as a Tiled app.  I have checked out the link you have given me and I think that is what I am after so thanks for your help.